# ¿Cómo mostrar datos en un DataTable usando AJAX, JSON, y PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, json, datatables

Estoy tratando de listar datos en una tabla, sin datatable me funciona bien, pero al momento de implementar el datatable me manda error, el error es :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Estoy utilizando JSON para poder mostrar los registros. Este es mi codigo js:

```
 <script>        
$(document).ready( function () {
showuser();

}); 

 function showuser() {
    $('#usuariostable').DataTable( {
        "ajax":({
          url: 'listar.php',
          type: 'get',
          success: function(response){
        const tasks = JSON.parse(response);
        let template = '';
        tasks.forEach(task => {
          template += `
                  <tr taskId="${task.id_usuario}">
                  <td>${task.id_usuario}</td>
                  <td>
                  <a href="#" class="task-item">
                    ${task.cec} 
                  </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button class="task-delete btn btn-danger">
                     Delete 
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary editarregistro" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">editar</button>

                  </td>
                  </tr>
                `
        });
        $('#usuarios').html(template);
          }
        })
    } );
  }

</script>
```

Este es mi codigo de mi archivo listar.php:

```
<?php
include('../conexion/dbconect.php');

        $query = "SELECT * from siacc_usuarios";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  if(!$result) {
    die('Error de consulta'. mysqli_error($con));
  }

  $json = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $json[] = array(
      'cec' => $row['cec'],
      'id_usuario' => $row['id_usuario']

    );
  }
  $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
  echo $jsonstring;
```

Alguien sabe por que me da ese error? si no utilizo datatable me funciona bien, pero quiero implementarlo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el output de listar.php?

Comment: Además, talvez tengas un error en el nombre `dbconect.php`.

Comment: Hola Luis, estas usando mal al sintaxis de DataTables.
https://datatables.net/manual/ajax